# extract array from an object php

Tags: php

hi i have the following object that i've printed with print_r

```
        Facebook\GraphObject Object ( 
        [backingData:protected] => Array ( [id] => xxxxxxxxxx
        [first_name] => xxx 
        [gender] => xxx 
        [last_name] => xxx 
        [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxxxxxx/ 
        [locale] => fr_FR 
        [name] => xxx [timezone] => x
        [updated_time] => xxx 
        [verified] => x ) )
```

what is the write piece of code that i could use to extract the array from this object

Comment: do you want to extract a specific array which is inside the object or you want to convert the whole object to array ?

Comment: @Khalid  i want to extract the array that contains id , first_name , ........ and all of that

Answer (score 0):

There is an `asArray()` method available. So:

```
$arr = $obj->asArray();
```

References:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0
- https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/src/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphObject.php#L88

Answer (score 0):

Well , the problem you have is that the array you want to get is protected, I suggest you to create a function inside your class like this

```
function get_Array()
{
   return $this->backingData;
}
```

and you can get the array you need like this

```
$Array = $Obj->get_Array();
$id = $Array['id'] ;
$first_name = $Array['frist_name'];
```